# Как удалить строку из JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Я хочу удалить некоторые строки из JTable. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Jtable есть своя модель, можно взять default или можно описать свою.
С помощью подели ты уже и сможешь видоизменять свою таблицу.
[Вот здесь описано подробно](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5,5);
JTable jTable = new JTable(model);
model.removeRow(2);
model.addRow(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((DefaultTableModel)myJTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowToRemove);
```